# redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error UNKNOWN while writing to socket. Connection lost

Tags: python, redis, redis-py, aioredis

For my python `(python 3.10)` based project, we were using aioredis `(aioredis 2.0.1)` to connect to redis cache and all of a sudden all the requests accessing redis cache started failing. After analysis, we found that [Aioredis is now in redis-py](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis-py). Post that we removed aioredis and added redis `(redis 4.5.1)` as a dependency in pipfile.

I didn't added any extra code just changed the imports from

```
import aioredis
```

to

```
from redis import asyncio as aioredis
```

But that didn't resolve the issue completely, now half of the requests are failing with the error code as below.(In an hour 145 requests were success while 79 failed)

> redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error UNKNOWN while writing to
> socket. Connection lost

we use aioredis.Redis for connection

```
aioredis.Redis(
            host=redis_hostname,
            port=redis_port,
            db=db_name,
            password=redis_password,
            ssl=true,
            connection_pool=aioredis.ConnectionPool.from_url(
                f"{redis_protocol}://:{redis_password}@{redis_hostname}:{redis_port}/{db_name}",
                connection_class=aioredis.Connection,
                max_connections=redis_pool_size,
            )
```

Below is the error trace

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py,
> line 788, in send_packed_command    await self._writer.drain()
>
> File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/streams.py, line 371, in
> drain    await self._protocol._drain_helper()
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ddtrace/contrib/asgi/middleware.py,
> line 173, in **call**    return await self.app(scope, receive,
> wrapped_send)
>
> File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/streams.py, line 167, in
> _drain_helper    raise ConnectionResetError('Connection
> lost')ConnectionResetError: Connection lost The above exception was
> the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> .....
>
> File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/client.py,
> line 487, in _send_command_parse_response    await
> conn.send_command(*args)redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error
> UNKNOWN while writing to socket. Connection lost.

Comment: We have the same issue.
Python 3.10.10
django-redis 5.2.0 (which also uses Redis 4.5.1)

The exception is the same, and the behaviour very similar. I can help test possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks @vsobotka, right now the solution which has worked for us is to retry.  Whenever we face a connection error we retry to connect and it works (able to acquire a connection). It's a temporary fix until we get to the root cause of the problem. Hope it helps

Comment: In our case, the cause was an improper use of the async api. We were using the asyncio.get_event_loop() and were working with the loop. Instead just awaiting in case we were in an async context, or using Django's async_to_sync in sync context solved the issues. We had this on several places in the app, raising all kinds of exceptions. This specific exception was when we ere using the event loop directly. Hope that helps.

Comment: Also try installing hiredis package, as it is used by redis-py. When available, it seems to be using its parser, which also resolved one of our exception.